# Pass in arguments from Jenkins to Gradle plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle

Using the Gradle plugin on Jenkins how do I pass project parameters in? There seems to be no parameters options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle seem to call these 'switches' which there is indeed an option for.

Comment: just for clarification: 'switch' is not a gradle term, but used by the plugin.

Comment: How would it work if I have 2 parameters in Jenkins job and I'm using Gradle (Build action) and in switches option box is I give "-Pkoba=$lori -Plori=$koba", then it seems like Jenkins is already passing the parameters to Gradle (for free) i.e. i see the end command becomes: "-Dkoba=LORI -Dlori=KOBA -Pkoba=LORI -Plori=KOBA", what can I do to tell Jenkins NOT to send the first 2 -D parameters (if I have those 2 parameters in the Jenkins job). In my case, I want the parameters to Gradle to be passed as -Pvar=$val instead of using -Dvar=$val